# Reusing same predicate instance in criteria query give wrong result

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Iam creating dynamic queries using criteria builder in Eclipselink. I creates predicate for each qualifier for eg. LIKE here.

```
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.like(expression, criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class, //Any string));
```

If I rerun the same query using that predicate instance it fetched wrong rows

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Address> countCriteria = cb.createQuery(Address.class);

    countCriteria.select(predicate);

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

Fetching in first run :

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.ADDRESSLINE1, t1.ADDRESSLINE2, t1.PHONENUMBER, t1.cityId, t1.personId FROM PERSON t0, ADDRESS t1 WHERE (t0.LASTNAME LIKE ? AND (t0.ID = t1.personId))
```

Fetching in the second run :

```
SELECT t2.ID, t2.ADDRESSLINE1, t2.ADDRESSLINE2, t2.PHONENUMBER, t2.cityId, t2.personId FROM PERSON t0, ADDRESS t2, ADDRESS t1 WHERE (t0.LASTNAME LIKE ? AND (t0.ID = t1.personId))
```

I found resembling thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648142/second-execution-of-the-same-criteriaquery-generates-wrong-sql). But not satisfied.

Comment: Predicates are tied to the CriteriaBuilder they were created from.  You should reuse the query, not the expressions.

Comment: @Chris Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Not reliably.  CriteriaBuilders are builders for a specific query.  You might try holding onto a single builder rather than getting a new one from the EM for new queries, but I don't see any value in it and it still may not work for you.  Builders and the predicates are light weight, so there isn't much use in caching them.  Rebuild them as needed is likely the best option.